# Django group by yield wrong result after filtering by annotated field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

So, I mainly want to group by my result by a certain field which I know I can do like

```
ModelName.objects.values('somefield').annotate(freq=Count('somefield'))
```

But before that, I want to filter based on one annotated field, but this yields the wrong result, I tried,

```
# Works fine
filtered_queryset = ModelName.objects.annotate(c=Count('related_field')).filter(c__gt=0)
# Yields wrong result.
filtered_queryset.values('somefield').annotate(freq=Count('somefield'))
```

I tried passing `distinct=True` but this didn't solve my problem.
Why am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have a defined `ModelName.Meta.ordering` by any chance?

If that's the case then you'll want to `order_by()` to clear it out else the referenced columns will be included in the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

This is a common footgun by the way and will be getting [warned about in Django 2.2 and removed in Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#model-meta-ordering-will-no-longer-affect-group-by-queries).

Comment: I tried what you said but this also didn't work, by the way you suggested ```filtered_queryset = ModelName.objects.annotate(c=Count('related_field')).filter(c__gt=0).order_by()
```
or
```filtered_queryset.values('somefield').annotate(freq=Count('somefield')) .order_by()
```
?

Comment: No, I have not defined ordering on this model.